# Iterate form field all together in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has input field as well as select field.I need to fetch both input and select field values using following function:-

```
$(' #form input').each(function() {
    var currentid = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Here i get access to input fields only, how can i get access to select field too?

Please help

Comment: `$(' #form input, #form select')`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan thank you so much, it is working.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan could you please post as answer i can accept the answer as well,once again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$('#form input').each(function() {
    var currentid = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

to this

```
$('#form :input').each(function() {
    var currentid = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

`:input` is a jQuery selector

Refer **[here](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually $('#form input') will work but this was not my doubt, anyways i got the answer , $(' #form input, #form select')

Comment: I answered your doubt by changing `input` to `:input`. It will work for other elements including input and select. Still, good to know that you have found the answer anyway.....